# Does Chrome Sync Save Your Google Account Password In The Clear?

Tags: google-chrome, passwords

Does Chrome Sync save your Google account password in the clear when "encrypt synced passwords with your google credentials" is checked? Or is it saving a hashed form of the password?

Comment: No; If you encrypt your passwords then your passwords are encrypted;

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that it would be stored in plain text, especially since you have an option for "*encrypt* synced passwords" checked. However, it must be reversible somehow, otherwise there's no way it could fill the password into forms.